# Using MySQL "SET" column with Ebean ORM

Tags: java, mysql, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to recreate one of our web apps using Play 2.0 with Ebean and I've hit a road block. I can't figure out how to map MySQL's `SET` type to a field in the model. I've gotten `ENUM` columns working using the `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation but I can't seem to find any info on `SET` columns.

The table mimics a crontab:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schedule` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `task_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `month` set('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December') default NULL,
  `mday` set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','-1','-2','-3','-4','-5','-6','-7','-8','-9','-10') default NULL,
  `wday` set('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday') default NULL,
  `hour` set('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23') default NULL,
  `minute` set('00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59') default NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `event` (`task_id`)
)
```

I've now created a UserType and related annotations as suggested by MvG:

```
@Entity
public class Schedule extends Model {

    public enum Month { JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER };
    public enum Weekday { SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY };

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    public Task task;
    @Version
    public Timestamp updated;

    @Type(type="models.EnumSetUserType",parameters=@Parameter(name="enumType",value="models.Schedule$Month"))
    @Column(name="month", columnDefinition="SET('JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTOBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER')")
    @MonthEnum
    public EnumSet<Month> months;

    @Type(type="models.IntegerSetUserType")
    @IntegerSet(min=-30,max=30)
    @Column(name="mday",columnDefinition="SET('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','-1','-2','-3','-4','-5','-6','-7','-8','-9')")
    public Set<Integer> mdays;

    @Type(type="models.EnumSetUserType", parameters = @Parameter(name="enumType", value="models.Schedule$Weekday"))
    @Column(name="wday", columnDefinition="SET('MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY')")
    @WeekdayEnum
    public EnumSet<Weekday> weekdays;

    @Type(type="models.IntegerSetUserType")
    @IntegerSet(min=0,max=23)
    @Column(name="hour",columnDefinition="SET('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23')")
    public Set<Integer> hours;

    @Type(type="models.IntegerSetUserType")
    @IntegerSet(min=0,max=59)
    @Column(name="minute",columnDefinition="SET('00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59')")
    public Set<Integer> minutes;

    public static Finder<Long,Schedule> find = new Finder<Long,Schedule>(Long.class, Schedule.class);

}
```

`EnumSetUserType`:

```
public class EnumSetUserType<E extends Enum<E>> implements UserType, ParameterizedType, Serializable {
    private Class<? extends EnumSet> clazz = null;
    private Class<E> enum_type = null;

    @Override
    public void setParameterValues(Properties parameters) {
        String enum_class_name = parameters.getProperty("enumType");
        try {
            enum_type = ReflectHelper.classForName(parameters.getProperty("enumType"), this.getClass()).asSubclass(Enum.class);
            //enum_type = (Class<E>) Class.forName(enum_class_name);
            //enum_type = (Class<E>) Play.application().classloader().loadClass(enum_class_name);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("enum class " + enum_class_name + " not found", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] column_names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String value_str = rs.getString(column_names[0]);
        System.out.println("getting " + column_names[0] + " using " + getClass());
        if (rs.wasNull())
            return null;

        List<E> enum_values = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (String value : value_str.split(","))
            enum_values.add(Enum.valueOf(enum_type, value));

        return EnumSet.copyOf(enum_values);
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object object, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        System.out.println("Setting " + index + " to " + object + " using " + getClass());
        if (object == null) {
            statement.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
            return;
        }

        Set<E> values = (Set<E>) object;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (E value : values)
            sb.append(value.name()).append(",");

        System.out.println("Setting " + index + " to " + sb.length() + " using " + getClass());
        statement.setString(index, sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1));
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.VARCHAR };
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        if (x == y)
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

}
```

It no longer reports any errors, but even when I manually populate and save a `Schedule` in a controller action, the `Set` fields aren't saved in the database. How can I get Play+Ebean to work with this table?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126029/how-to-map-a-set-of-enum-type-in-hibernate

Comment: I...can't really tell. It's hard to get my bearings when everything is called `Wicket`, and I'm not sure how the XML configuration would map to annotations.

Answer (score 0):

If you map an `ENUM` column to a Java Enumeration, you should probably map a `SET` column to a Java [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html). There is at least [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2402869/1468366) on SF about mapping `EnumSet`, but the solution there appears to be a separate table, not the mysql `SET` type.

It also appears that there is no support in hybernate for mysql `SET` types. Therefore, you'll have to write your own [`UserType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html). I'm not sure about the difference, but it seems you could easily make this an [`EnhancedUserType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/EnhancedUserType.html), which would probably make your implementation more versatile. If your project allows using LGPL-licensed source code, you might use [the implementation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/EnumType.java) of [`EnumType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/EnumType.html) as a template for your own `EnumSetType`. Adapting that should be easy, particularly as you could throw away all the “save as ordinal” parts of the code.

Once you have your own `UserType` for `EnumSet`, you could annotate the corresponding fields with that [`@Type`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Type.html). Or in the hibernation configuration, if there is such a thing in your setup. There might be even ways to register the type somewhere, to automatically map all `EnumSet` instances using that type, but I know too little about this whole hibernation stuff to decide whether this is desirable or even possible. I haven't even figured out yet how the [`@Enumerated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html) annotation maps to the `EnumType` implementation.

With the right keywords (`UserType EnumSet split`), one can [find](http://www.google.com/search?q=UserType%20EnumSet%20split) some implementations on the web. So you wouldn't even have to write your own code, but could simply include one of these solutions. Some come with a short description about how to use them.

Comment: using `EnumSet` results in "org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: models.Schedule.months". Or if I remove `@ElementCollection` it just pretends it doesn't exist.

Comment: @bemace: OK, I've edited my answer to include more details on custom type mappings.