# Why List<valueObject> giving Error in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

In my Java Application creating Value Object(Java Bean) in that have one field

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EC_TIMETABLE")
    public class TimetableVO
{
----//@id and some other column and variables
----

private List<WeekdayType> repeatDays;//Their is No column in Database
------
------//setter and getter method
}
```

Hear WeekdayType is Enum class

```
public static enum WeekdayType {
    MONDAY(Calendar.MONDAY), TUESDAY(Calendar.TUESDAY), WEDNESDAY(
            Calendar.WEDNESDAY), THURSDAY(Calendar.THURSDAY), FRIDAY(
            Calendar.FRIDAY), SATURDAY(Calendar.SATURDAY), SUNDAY(
            Calendar.SUNDAY);

    private int day;

    private WeekdayType(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
```

I'm using TimetableVO getRepeatedDays() another class.

When i'm Start the Server i got error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: EC_TIMETABLE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(repeatDays)]
```

So is their any Column required in Database or Syntax Problem .....
Thank in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need not have a column in database for this field if you do not want to.

You can mark it as transient by @Transient annotation if you do not want to make it persistent.

```
@Transient
private List<WeekdayType> repeatDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

Marking the collection as transient will instruct Hibernate that this is not a persisted item.  I think something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126029/how-to-map-a-set-of-enum-type-in-hibernate) is more in line with what you require.

Answer (score 0):

**JPA's @Transient annotation is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database, i.e. their semantics are different.**

Now the solution is ...

```
@Transient
private List<WeekdayType> repeatDays;
```